# C++/STL Graphviz and Boost - Seg Fault Problem

Tags: c++, boost, stl, graphviz

I am using the dot language to create a graph using Boost. My Graphs are huge and I am trying to delete graphs that are no longer used.

Under boost/graph/graphviz.hpp
I added a function to remove a vertex:

```
    virtual void
  do_remove_vertex( const node_t& node)
  {
    bgl_vertex_t v = bgl_nodes[node];
    clear_vertex(v,graph_);
    remove_vertex(v,graph_);
  }
```

However I keep getting a segfault on the call to clear vertex, I ran it into gdb and here is the back trace (i hope this is not to long)

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040b87f in std::_List_base<boost::detail::sep_<void*, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int, boost::no_property> >, std::allocator<boost::detail::sep_<void*, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int, boost::no_property> > > >::_M_clear (this=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/list.tcc:68
68       _Node* __cur = static_cast<_Node*>(this->_M_impl._M_node._M_next);
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040b87f in std::_List_base<boost::detail::sep_<void*, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int, boost::no_property> >, std::allocator<boost::detail::sep_<void*, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int, boost::no_property> > > >::_M_clear (this=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/list.tcc:68
#1  0x00000000004119d2 in std::list<boost::detail::sep_<void*, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int, boost::no_property> >, std::allocator<boost::detail::sep_<void*, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int, boost::no_property> > > >::clear (this=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_list.h:1132
#2  0x000000000040fac4 in boost::clear_vertex<boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string, boost::no_property>, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string, boost::no_property>, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config> (u=0x0, g_=...) at boost_1_43_0/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:633
#3  0x000000000040e7a5 in boost::detail::graph::mutate_graph_impl<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string, boost::no_property>, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS> >::do_remove_vertex (this=0x7fffffffe520, node=...)
    at boost_1_43_0/boost/graph/graphviz.hpp:767
#4  0x00007ffff7b6ab12 in boost::read_graphviz_detail::translate_results_to_graph (r=..., mg=0x7fffffffe520) at ../../../libs/graph/src/read_graphviz_new.cpp:782
#5  0x00007ffff7b6b314 in boost::detail::graph::read_graphviz_new (str=..., mg=0x7fffffffe520) at ../../../libs/graph/src/read_graphviz_new.cpp:830
#6  0x000000000040bc1f in boost::read_graphviz_new<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string, boost::no_property>, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS> > (str=..., graph=..., dp=..., node_id=...)
    at boost_1_43_0/boost/graph/detail/read_graphviz_new.hpp:103
#7  0x000000000040b243 in boost::read_graphviz<std::istream_iterator<char, char, std::char_traits<char>, long>, boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string, boost::no_property>, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS> > (
    user_first=..., user_last=..., graph=..., dp=..., node_id=...) at boost_1_43_0/boost/graph/graphviz.hpp:910
#8  0x000000000040aa18 in boost::read_graphviz<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string, boost::no_property>, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int, boost::no_property>, boost::no_property, boost::listS> > (in=..., graph=..., dp=..., node_id=...)
    at boost_1_43_0/boost/graph/graphviz.hpp:922
#9  0x00000000004086a9 in test_graph_read_write (filename=...) at graphviz.cpp:41
#10 0x0000000000408814 in main () at graphviz.cpp:52
```

Any Ideas??? As I am pretty lost.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems like a different problem - try to run it under valgrind.

Comment: Sigh, these heap corruption questions are just a bottom-less pit at SO.  Everybody corrupts it their own way, is it ever a dup?  Voting to close as 'too localized', too lazy to try to find the generic answer.

Comment: My best guess: Check what is contained in the variable v. Does it point to the heap? Is it modified in any way by the function clear_vertex? It seems possible that you are destroying information about the object on the second line and then trying to use it on the third. Not sure if that is it, but that is where I would start.

Comment: Well it doesn't look like stack corruption. It does look, however, like something is not properly initialized because NULL pointer is passed to a function, and it seems like pointer to std::list, which clear () method is invoked and finally crashed in dereferencing "this", which is 0x0:

#0  0x000000000040b87f in std::_List_base<...>::_M_clear (this=0x0)
#1  0x00000000004119d2 in std::list...::clear (this=0x0)...
#2  0x000000000040fac4 in ... (u=0x0, g_=...)...

Answer (score 0):

Problem was when Read Graphviz function reads in a dot file, it does NOT create the DFG in the same order, thus breaking my deleting function.